# How to have different head & footer rule widths on odd and even pages using fancyhdr?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, rules

I am trying to create a document that has just a footer on odd pages and just a header on even pages. On the odd pages, there should be a head rule width of 0pt and a foot rule width of 0.4pt. On the even pages, there should be a foot rule width of 0pt and a head rule width of 0.4pt. I know how to set up everything but the rule width alternations. How can I do the alternations for the headrulewidths and footrulewidths?

Here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,twocolumn]{article}  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{normalpage}{
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancyhead[LO]{} 
\fancyhead[RO]{}
\fancyfoot[LO]{{\footnotesize  \textbf{Title}} \textbullet ~ \footnotesize Vol. 1, Number 1, 2016 \textbullet ~Text}
\fancyfoot[CO]{}
\fancyfoot[RO]{ \thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{{\footnotesize  \textbf{Title}} \textbullet ~ \footnotesize Vol. 1, Number 1, 2016 \textbullet ~Text}
\fancyhead[RE]{ \thepage}
\fancyfoot[LE]{}
\fancyfoot[CE]{}
\fancyfoot[RE]{}
}

\pagestyle{normalpage}
\begin{document}

Text
\cleardoublepage
Text

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want to use fancyhdr then you need \pagestyle{fancy}.  The header/footer width is the same as textwidth.  If you want to exceed the margins you will need to use things like \rlap, \llap and \hbox to ??.

Comment: @JohnKormylo That's not true. You don't have to use `\pagestyle{fancy}` even though that is the most common way to do it because the package defines the style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

[image: fancy switching]

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\let\origheadrule\headrule
\let\origfootrule\footrule
\fancypagestyle{normalpage}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
  \fancyhf[rof,reh]{\thepage}%
  \fancyhf[lof,leh]{{\footnotesize  \textbf{Title}} \textbullet ~ \footnotesize Vol. 1, Number 1, 2016 \textbullet ~Text}%
  \def\headrule{%
      \ifodd\value{page}\relax\else\origheadrule\fi}%
  \def\footrule{%
    \ifodd\value{page}\origfootrule\else\fi}%

}
\pagestyle{normalpage}
\begin{document}

Text
\cleardoublepage
Text

\end{document}
```